# Add column in position number two in csv file in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a lot of different CSV files with data in it (including headers).

I can't figure it out how to add a new column in the position number two.

I can fill the new cell with the null value (each row) but the new column is in first position.

Please see attachment image : the new column it must be after the column IDINTA.

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

My code below.

```
output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target.csv");

string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(output);
List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList()).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
{
    CSV[i].Insert(0, i == 0 ? "Headername" : "Filename");
}
File.WriteAllLines(output, CSV.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
```

**#Edit 01**

[image]

**#Edit 02**

```
N|IDINTA|Filename|DDMMYYYY HHMMSS|
```

Comment: The way I can think of is; to convert csv to DataTable. Once data is there in DataTable, you can add column at whatever position you want.

Comment: So which of the columns is the one you want to insert? Can you show us what it should look like before and after?

Comment: @wkl please see #Edit 02 in my first question

Comment: Can you please explain which of csv tables is before, which is after and what the third one is?

Comment: @wkl : I need add new column **Filename** in csv file between column **IDINTA** and **DDMMYYYY HHMMSS**

Comment: @wkl The index must be within the limits of the list. Parameter name: index

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post an image of your sample data instead of text for the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the index in your `Insert` statement:

```
CSV[i].Insert(2, i == 0 ? "Headername" : "Filename");
```

Using a variable for the desired position, the complete code would be:

```
// define the desired position here:
int posNewColumn = 2;

output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target.csv");

string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(output);
List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList()).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
{
    if( CSV[i].Count > posNewColumn)
    {
        CSV[i].Insert(posNewColumn , i == 0 ? "Headername" : "Filename");
    }
    else 
    {
    // append the new data at the end if the existing line is too short.
    // You may want to do nothing instead or fill the appropriate number
    // of empty cells before adding.
        CSV[i].Add(i == 0 ? "Headername" : "Filename");
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(output, CSV.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
```

Comment: Thank you for help. please see **#Edit 01** in my first question

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq If you get an error that the index must be within the limits of the list, I assume that there is a line in your csv which is shorter than the others. You should check for that. If this is a requirement, add it to the question.

Comment: it's possible that there is a line in your csv which is shorter than the others, but are hundreds of rows

Comment: edited. When the line is not long enough, we append it at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/public/target.csv");

string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(output);

var CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList());

var newInserted = CSV.Aggregate(new List<List<String>>(), (l, i) =>
{
    i.Insert(1, (l.Count == 0) ? "header" : "fileName");
    l.Add(i);
    return l;
});

File.WriteAllLines(output, newInserted.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but with your code the new column is not added.

Comment: lemme check, then, it's not appearing in the newInserted variable?

Comment: oops should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, the new column is not added

Comment: are you looking the CSV variable for the new column?

Comment: Yes but the variable is not added

Comment: I've replaced the last line where it writes the data.  It should be there now

Comment: Ok, now I have the new column **Filename** in csv file in last position but also in position numer two....

Comment: I'm confused, do you want it as the last position or the second?